# Fastlink Mandatory? Or build your own?

Tags: yodlee

I am brand new to YODLEE API.
Is it mandatory to use Fastlink? Is Fastlink mobile responsive?
What if I want to build my own instead of using Fastlink? Do you have any guides to help?

Comment: Looks like you got a good answer below that covers most of your questions, but not the mobile/responsive, which I am very interested in knowing.  I created a distinct question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201853/is-there-yodlee-fastlink-configuration-that-is-mobile-aware-or-responsive

Answer (score 1):

FastLink is not mandatory. You can definitely use SiteBased APIs for having this flow handled. However, there are certain advantages you would have if you use Fastlink, like the add/Edit account flow is completely handled by Yodlee and that would reduce your coding drastically.

There is lot of documentation around this on our Developer portal @ [Add Site Account](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation/Aggregation_Services/Add_Site_Account)

Hope this helps, Happy coding .