# Is there Yodlee FastLink configuration that is mobile-aware or responsive?

Tags: yodlee

FastLink looks good stand-alone and in an 800x600 iFrame in the desktop browser, but I'm hoping there are some more mobile-friendly configurations that I just missed in the docs.

I see the access_type and displayMode parameters here, which would imply that what I'm hoping for is at least a possibility:

http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide

I've been unable to find any other reference to those parameters in the docs, however, or more detail with regard to layout options.

Are there some other valid values for those parameters other than what's listed there in the Integration Guide, and/or some more detailed docs besides the integration guide and product guide?

FastLink looks like it has the potential to save significant unanticipated work on account setup, especially MFA -- I'm hoping we can get the FastLink UX to gel nicely enough with our own UX to not have to invest in rolling our own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no Fastlink available for Mobile/responsive one, although its in works and will be available in near future(no specific ETA right now).

Comment: Hi @Apoorv, I know this is asking a lot, but do you have any idea on the ETA (even a guess)?  1 month, 6 months, 1 year?  I have to support mobile and don't want to write my own solution only to have Yodlee release a mobile-friendly version 2 weeks later.

Comment: @KevinZych- Right now as a guess I should say for ALPHA release it would be April/May.

Comment: With respect to the Fastlink oAuth 'displayMode' launch parameter, are there options other than **desktop** that we may pass to get other application styles? Even if they are experimental, it may help for the purpose of our application.